# Sci-Kit Learn FeatureUnion with different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-extraction

I am trying to use the FeatureUnion functionality of scikit-learn Pipelines on a project where the data is in a database. I am having some foundational issues in how to structure what I'm doing.

I am creating two features from two different tables in the database. I have a fetch_x1, fetch_x2 method to grab the data of interest from the database tables as pandas DataFrames. I packs the two DataFrames into a dictionary of dataframe. In each transformer, I unpack the DataFrame of interest and operate on it. I'm kind of following the pattern of this [post](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py).

My code is below:

```
class Feature1Extractor(TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, dictionary_of_dataframes):
        df = dictionary_of_dataframes['feature1_raw_data']
        x = df.groupby('user_id').count()['x1']
        return df

class Feature2Extractor(TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, dictionary_of_dataframes):
        df = dictionary_of_dataframes['feature2']
        x = df.groupby('user_id').sum()['x2']
        return x

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            ('feature1', Feature1Extractor()),
            ('feature2', Feature2Extractor())])),
    ('null', None)
])

pipeline.transform(dictionary_of_dataframes)
```

I'm running into another more foundational issue -- after transformation the two feature matrices that come out of each pipeline have a **different number of rows**. Consequently, the simple hstack at the end of FeatureUnion is failing like so:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

This is fundamental to the data I have.  There are a number of user_ids that are not present in the feature1 table, similarly there a number of user_ids that are not present in the feature2 table.  This is fundamental to the data -- if a user has no data in the feature1 table, he/she never used that feature in the app, e.g. no data = no engagement with that feature.  To make the example explicit, here's an example of the two df's that are being passed to each transformer:

df (for feature1)

```
user_id, x1, timestamp
1, 'click', 1/1/2016
1, 'click', 1/2/2016
2, 'click', 1/2/2016
```

df (for feature2)

```
user_id, x2, timestamp
2, 12.3, 1/2/2016
3, 14,5, 1/4/2016
```

Note how the DataFrame for feature1 does not have user 3, and the DataFrame for feature2 does not have user 1.  When I did this without Pipelines, I would do an outer join and then fillna(0) on the resulting merged dataframe, e.g.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df1, how='outer', left_on=['user_id'], right_on=['user_id'])
final_df = merged_df.fillna(0)
```

But there does not seem to be any way to do this using the FeatureUnion method. And I can't seem to think of a clean workaround in the Pipeline framework... I have to run separate pipelines, transform each of them, do the outer join and fillna in pandas, and then run the completed feature matrix into a downstream modelling pipeline?  Is there a better way? Looking to the community for help.

NOTE: I do NOT know the user_ids before hand. I am querying the tables based on the timestamp range... not user_id. The query itself tells me what users I should have in the training (or test) set.

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're asking. Give us some example data, or a small input/output so that we can verify the problem you're having. I'm  not sure why you can't fill one data set to just have the same number of rows as the other (fill it with `None`s or something), and then do the FeatureUnion

Comment: You are right, I will edit appropriately... I don't know all the user_ids before hand though--- that's why I was doing an outer join ... i don't want to keep track of that separately. I will edit this to be more focused with a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Why, won't you build your own, pandas based union?
Something like this... (I didn't tested it, just see the idea)

```
class DataMerging(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self):
        return self

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, dfs):
        df1, df2 = dfs
        merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on=['user_id'], right_on=['user_id']).fillna(0)
        return merged_df.values #(return shape (n_features, n_samples))


pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('union', DataMerging,
    ('other thing', ...)
])        

pipeline.fit(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Ok this is interesting -- but I'm not completely understanding how this fits into the Pipeline description... Also, should I subclass FeatureUnion?